# Where is changed menu in project tool window of IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.5?

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA project tool window, there are several menu items like Project, Packages, Project Files, Problems, Production, Tests, Android instrumentation tests, Scratches.

But I can't find Changed menu recently from which I can check modified local files.

I use svn 1.9.3 in local, is there any one who knows turn on changes menu in Project tool window?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [known bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-162583). Try [2017.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/) version.